# How to bind Interfaces to Methods using LightInject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, light-inject

In Ninject when I wanted to bind NHibernate's ISession to a method I'd do :

```
container.Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(CreateSession).InRequestScope();
```

While the method is :

```
private ISession CreateSession(IContext context)
{
    var sessionFactory = context.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>();
    if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(sessionFactory))
    {
        var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
    }
    return sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
}
```

How can I do the same with LightInject?

Comment: How far did you get on this?

Comment: There's no Equivalent in LightInject. But there are still Typed Factories, which are nice.

Comment: Just started playing with LightInject (I was using Ninject) for performance and ease of use.  Read: avoiding 500lb gorillas (Unity & Castle).  I'll post what I ended up with later this evening and we can compare notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact equivalent is the following:

```
container.Register<ISession>(factory => CreateSession(factory), new PerRequestLifeTime());
```

where CreateSession becomes:

```
private ISession CreateSession(IServiceFactory factory)
{
    var sessionFactory = factory.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>();
    if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(sessionFactory))
    {
        var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
    }
    return sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
}
```

**Edit**: Actualy, this is not the "exact" equivalent, because NInject's InRequestScope is related to the web request while LightInject's PerRequestLifeTime means "PerGetInstanceCall". 
What you would need then is to get [LightInject Web extension](http://www.lightinject.net/#web) and intialize the container this way:

```
var container = new ServiceContainer();
container.EnablePerWebRequestScope();                   
container.Register<IFoo, Foo>(new PerScopeLifetime());
```

and use the PerScopeLifetime instead of PerRequestLifeTime